# yarn workspace deploy into a docker image

Tags: yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspaces and I have this packages in my package.json:

"workspaces": ["packages/*"]
I am trying to create a docker image to deploy and I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# production dockerfile
FROM node:9.2

# add code
COPY ./packages/website/dist /cutting

WORKDIR /cutting

COPY package.json /cutting/
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile && yarn cache clean --production

CMD npm run serve
```

But I get the following error:

error An unexpected error occurred:
"https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@cutting%2futil: Not found"

@cutting/util is the name of one of my workspace packages.

So the problem is that there is no source code in the docker image so it is trying to install it from yarnpkg.

what is the best way to handle workspaces when deploying to a docker image?

Say my structure is:

```
root
 |_node_modules
        -----|_ package_1
        -----|_package_2
        -----|_package_3
        -----|_deploy_pkg
```

I want to deploy `deploy_pkg` but I have no idea how to create a bundle I can just copy into the docker image